# Cucumber : Find all unimplemented step definitions for java project

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber

I want to get all the Unimplemented step defenitions while building the project so that i can make sure we will never endup missing any such mistakes.
Am using Cucumber with serenity. What i need is a dependency or some thing which can report all the unimplemented steps in the project.

Comment: Just use the `dryRun` option.